# How can I completely remove a global option from R with options()

Tags: r

I have added to R a global option `$blogdown.hugo.dir = "C:/Hugo"` 
which makes `devtools::check()` crash.

```
-- Checking ------------------------------------------ eurobarometer --
Setting env vars:
* _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_: FALSE
* _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_       : FALSE
* _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_      : FALSE
-- R CMD check -------------------------------------------------------------
Error: 2:39: unexpected symbol
2: options(blogdown.hugo.dir = 'C:/Hugo').Last
                                          ^
Execution halted
```

I tried to set

```
options(blogdown.hugo.dir = 'C:/Hugo')
```

I re-installed with clear startup options *RStudio* and *R*, but I cannot remove the global option.  I can change it, but not remove it.

Can anyone point me out how to completely remove an element from options, or to get a fresh option. Many packages re-set settings, but only for standard ones, not custom options.

Comment: I will answer your question, but I doubt it will solve your problem. That error is being caused by the `.Last` rather than the call to `options`. If that is from your code, perhaps based on thinking that R is like an OOP language that you used in the past, then you should focus on fixing that. The "^" is used by the R syntax checker/parser to show where the problems lies within an expression.

Answer (score 5):

Look at `?options`. You should see a third item in the Usage list, `.Options`. That's actually the name of the structure that holds the names and values of options so you should be able to set a particular one to `NULL` which is the standard R method to remove items from lists. I tried with:

```
.Options$demo.ask <- NULL
```

Success.

I thought that that using `options(key = NULL)` will leave an entry in the `.Options` tree, since NULL is a valid value for a list item, but I was wrong. There's no such named value after that operation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I came as far, but when I did this, the option still kept coming back, so I made a search for whatever file may contain this option. The user set options are stored in the `.Renviron` file that turned out to have multiple copies after having installed consecutive  R versions over years in the same machine.

Furthermore, the .Last part probably came from a malformatted line without end in the `.Renviron`.

Apart from following the advice above, if the option keeps coming back, search for any possible copies of `.Renviron` that may be on a path where R can find it.

Comment: @DanielAntal There are multiple places where such code could be active. See `?Startup` for a complete description of locations that R runs when booting up. A `.Last`script could put extra options or change standard options in any of those locations.